# Why D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null?

Tags: android, android-studio

Im trying to build app that can save receipe with an image then we can display it in the Details menu
But i have a problem, the image doesnt appear, i dont know what happen but in database the byte saved.

Here is my Activity for save receipe

```
public class BuatResepActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected Cursor cursor;
    DataHelper dbHelper;
    Button ton1, ton2, butUp;
    EditText text1, text2, text3, text4, text5;
    ImageView imageResep;
    private String selectedImagePath;
    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
    String TABLE_NAME = "resep";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.buatresep_activity);

        dbHelper = new DataHelper(this);
        //text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etID);
        text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNamaResep);
        text3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etBahan);
        text4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLangkah);
        ton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSimpan);
        ton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBack);
        butUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upimage);
        imageResep = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewResep);

        butUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                        SELECT_PICTURE);

            }
        });

        ton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                byte[] byteImage1 = null;

                try {
                    FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream(selectedImagePath);
                    BufferedInputStream bif = new BufferedInputStream(instream);
                    byteImage1 = new byte[bif.available()];
                    bif.read(byteImage1);

                    db.execSQL("insert into resep( nama_resep, bahan, langkah, image) values('" +
                            text2.getText().toString() +"','" +
                            text3.getText().toString()+"','"+
                            text4.getText().toString()+"','"+
                            byteImage1+"')");


                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Berhasil", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    HomeActivity.ma.RefreshList();
                    finish();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error Exception : " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });

        ton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                String gambar = data.getData().toString();
                System.out.println("Data Image : "+gambar);
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
                imageResep.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageResep.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);

            }
        }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {

        String path = null;
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

        if(cursor == null){
            path = uri.getPath();
        }
        else{
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(projection[0]);
            path = cursor.getString(column_index);
            cursor.close();
        }

        return ((path == null || path.isEmpty()) ? (uri.getPath()) : path);
    }
}
```

And this is my Details Activity :

```
public class DetailResepActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected Cursor cursor;
    DataHelper dbHelper;
    Button ton2;
    TextView text1, text2, text3, text4, text5;
    ImageView imageResepD;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detailresep_activity);

        byte[] byteImage2 = null;

        dbHelper = new DataHelper(this);
        text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvID);
        text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNama);
        text3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBahan);
        text4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLangkah);
        imageResepD = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewResepD);
        //text5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM resep WHERE nama_resep = '" +
                getIntent().getStringExtra("nama_resep") + "'",null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor.getCount()>0)
        {
            cursor.moveToPosition(0);
            text1.setText(cursor.getString(0).toString());
            text2.setText(cursor.getString(1).toString());
            text3.setText(cursor.getString(2).toString());
            text4.setText(cursor.getString(3).toString());

        }

        byteImage2 = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("image"));
        System.out.println("Data Image Blob : "+byteImage2);
        setImage(byteImage2);
        ton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        ton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    void setImage(byte[] byteImage2) {
        imageResepD.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteImage2, 0,
                byteImage2.length));
        System.out.println("Size Image Blob : "+byteImage2.length);
        //textView.append("\n Image Size : " + byteImage2.length + " KB");
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```